# How to group a flat un-categorized list into sub lists using XSLT grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, muenchian-grouping

I am trying to group the following html content:

### input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Steps for grouping in the Muench method</h2>
        <p class="step">Define a <code>key</code> for the property we want
            to use for grouping.</p>
        <p class="step">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <p class="result">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <p class="step">For each unique grouping value ...</p>
        <h2>Steps for grouping in XSLT 2.0</h2>
        <p class="step">Define an XPath expression ...</p>
        <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        
        <p class="substep">Instead of dealing with each ...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

### into the following output

I had taken a look at a couple of answers here before posting it here. They gave an idea as to how to group the following siblings with the target element. For example, when I want to group element with @result inside substep. And each substep inside step.

```
<body>
        <h2>Steps for grouping in the Muench method</h2>
        <step>
            <p class="step">Define a <code>key</code> for the property we want to use for
                grouping.</p>
        </step>
        <step>
            <p class="step">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
            <substep>
                <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
                <p class="result">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
            </substep>
            <substep>
                <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
            </substep>
        </step>
        <step>
            <p class="step">For each unique grouping value ...</p>
            <h2>Steps for grouping in XSLT 2.0</h2>
        </step>
        <step>
            <p class="step">Define an XPath expression ...</p>
            <substep>
                <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
            </substep>
            <substep>
                <p class="substep">Instead of dealing with each ...</p>
            </substep>
        </step>
    </body>
```

### What I have done so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:key name="step" match="p" use="@class"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <body>
        <xsl:variable name="steps">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="html/body/*" group-starting-with="p[@class = 'step']">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-group()[self::p[@class = 'step']]">
                        <step>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </step>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$steps" mode="fix.step"/>
      </body>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="fix.step">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="step" mode="fix.step">
        <step>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@class = 'substep']">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-group()[self::p[@class = 'substep']]">
                        <substep>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </substep>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </step>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Questions

Is there a better to achieve the same result?

### a few caveats

The given input file is only an example. There could a lot of non @step and @substep elements between a @step and a @substep elements. And they need to be grouped within either step or substep depending on their position. For example, the following could be another variation of the input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Steps for grouping in the Muench method</h2>
        <p class="step">Define a <code>key</code> for the property we want
            to use for grouping.</p>
        <p class="step">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <p class="result">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <image @href="image.pn"/>
        <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <p class="result">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        <p class="step">For each unique grouping value ...</p>
        <h2>Steps for grouping in XSLT 2.0</h2>
        <p class="step">Define an XPath expression ...</p>
        <p class="substep">Select all of the nodes ...</p>
        
        <p class="substep">Instead of dealing with each ...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Rules

1. When a list item at level 1 has following siblings
   **p/@class=ListContinue** or p/@class=ListNote or p/@class=ListBullet2, all such adjacent elements should be wrapped
   in

   as well except where the p/@class = BodyText or
   p/@class=Note.

   When a list item at level 2 has following siblings
   **p/@class=ListContinue2** or p/@class=ListNote, all such adjacent elements should be wrapped in

   as well except where the p/@class
   = BodyText or p/@class=Note or p/@class=ListBullet.

That way, all info related to a particular list item are wrapped within li. The same logic applies to all li irrespective of the depth. It's that I am finding it difficult to achieve.

Comment: I see no Muenchian grouping or need for Muenchian grouping here. You have defined a key, but you are not using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>  

<xsl:template match="/html">
    <body>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="body/*" group-starting-with="p[@class='step']">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::p[@class='step']">
                    <step>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>     
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="p[@class='substep']">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="self::p[@class='substep']">
                                    <substep>
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                                    </substep> 
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>    
                    </step>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you @michael. It am still trying to understand how grouping works in XSLT. I was looking for a solution like the one you have posted. I ran your code against the second example in the question. The output does not include the image tag within step.

Comment: @Antony It is difficult to work with examples instead of rules. I made an adjustment to my answer, but it was meant only as a starting point for you to expand on as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me simplify the solution.

Comment: sorry for this stupid question. But it sounds like I need to change my approach. What do you mean by working with rules? Could you please elaborate on that if you don't mind? It might give me some insights into changing my thought process.

Comment: I meant that your question gave an example of input and output but did not elaborate the logic that needs to be applied.to the input in order to get the output. Later you added another example of input, but still left it to us to guess what the logic needs to be.My guess may work for you or not - I have no way of knowing.

Comment: sorry about that. when a list item is grouped, all its adjacent elements should be wrapped in <li> as well except where the p/@class = BodyText or p/@class=Note. That way, all info related to a particular list item are wrapped within li. The same logic applies to all li irrespective of the depth. It's that I am finding it difficult to achieve.

Comment: I added the rules.

Comment: Well, I am not going to spend more time on this. I think you have enough to make your adjustments - if not, post a new question.

Comment: That's ok. Thank you for your help.